# a linear transformation; what must be true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Imagine a object that is transformed into another, for example a car in xy-plane that is rotated 60 degrees. I know this can be done with linear tranformations using matrices, but how would one do it geomatrically, and what would the reason be when referring to the theoretics behind?

What I mean is, where would we rotate it from? Would we fix one point on the car, then rotate it around that point? And can we choose this point ourselves? If not, why, and how could one explain this while linking to the actual system behind it (which is the linear tranformation that consists of a matrix multiplied by a column vector).

Comment: The term "linear transformation" implies the use of vector spaces, which come with a zero element. In geometry, space does not come equipped with an origin, so it is more naturally described by an affine space than by a vector space. However, after choosing an origin, you _can_ identify each point in space with a vector (from the origin to that point). Only under this identification does applying a linear transformation make any sense. Also linear transformations must fix the origin. To describe linear transformations by matrices, you must in a addition choose a coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

Think of this as geometric vectors: the vector's "tail" is the origin **and it is pinned there** , and the vector's end is the car.

Now take this vector and rotate it whatever degrees (or radians) you want, holding the pin constant in its place (the origin), i.e. as if we had an axis through the origin whicn not only pins down vectors but also around which we can rotate vectors either direction and degrees we want to.

Comment: But can we think of the car as a vector? How would we do it in actuality? I'm thinking that we'd have a lot of points that will be represented by vectors, and then we'll transform each vector, get new points, connect them, and then we'll have our car?

Comment: @JacksonDan *I'm thinking that we'd have a lot of points that will be represented by vectors, and then we'll transform each vector, get new points, connect them, and then we'll have our car?* That's the right idea.  The point that gets "fixed" is whichever point you call the origin.

Comment: @JacksonDan note that the car consists of a lot of points which are already, in a sense, "connected".  When we apply the transformation, we'll end up with a new set of points forming the new car, and these points will be "connected" in the same sense.

Answer (score 2):

A linear transformation is a transformation of the form:
$$y = Ax$$
where $x$ is a vector in your space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$. In particular, a linear transformation will fix the origin of the axes, i.e. $A\cdot\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$. Therefore, if you use a linear transformation with a matrix that represents a rotation, you are rotating around the origin.

If you want to rotate around a point P that is different from the origin then you first translate P to the origin then rotate and then translate the origin back to P.

Comment: So have I understood correctly: the car consists of points that can be represented by vectors pinned at the origin. We transform each point by using the transformation on each vector and then we connect all the dots to get our new car... but since the zero vector points to the zero vector regardless of much we are rotating, it will be pinned there and so we'll always rotate around the origin?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom you are right, I mean any $n$-by-$n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. any matrix in $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @JacksonDan Yes, you are correct. The car is a set of points, and you can think of each point as the factor that connect the origin to that point.